# Xcopy transfer not working

Tags: xcopy

I am using the xcopy command to copy files from one directory to another.

I am saving in the text editor as a .bat file and then running as admin.

Here is the command.

**xcopy C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\Saved Spectral Files Z:\Contamination_Control\MOC Measurements\MOC Plates Data\Perkin Elmer Data Back-Up\ /d /f /p**

The problem is it doesn't work. Not even a notification that anything has happened.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

N

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert quotation marks around the two file paths, because without them, in my experience with xcopy, doesn't recognize the files. Sidenote: the same applies to the copy function.

Answer (score 0):

As an add-on to the previous answer:
The problem is your empty spaces " " within the paths. For the command to know where one path starts and ends, always use the quotation marks.